# Is there any tool for adding white spaces for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, whitespace

I'm migrating some codes from JS to Typescript. And quite annoyed by errors about white spaces.
Like spaces after comments, and around a equal.

I understand it is fairly good and makes sense.
But I think there is a automated tool or plugins for white spaces.
Please advice me a good solution.

> [00:15:40] [gulp-tslint] error app/world/world.component.ts[53, 20]: missing whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And quite annoyed by errors about white spaces. Like spaces after comments, and around a equal.

TypeScript does not error on these. Perhaps you are using `tslint`.

## Fix

- Disable tslint OR
- Use grunt to cleanup : https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-trimtrailingspaces OR
- Atom editor does this by default.

Comment: You're right, I should have shown the error message.

Comment: Cool is there anything else that still needs answering?  

Comment: no, thank you for letting me know that. 
I was using sublime text 2 and typescript plugin (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) and I have found it already has formatting feature so I could use it by `^T` `^F` ;)